# Есть ли для JupyterLab автодополнение кода?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Возник вопрос, есть ли для JupyterLab автодополнение кода не по нажатию Tab а автоматически, чтобы выдавала подсказку по коду?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Есть расширение
https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp (Language Server Protocol integration for Jupyter(Lab)).

Там кроме автодополнения еще есть куча всяких других фич:

- Подсказки при наведении
- Выделение ошибок в коде
- Переход к определению (jump to definition)
- Подсветка ссылок на объект
- Подсказка сигнатур функций
- Автодополнение без запущенного ядра jupyter (Kernel-less Autocompletion)
- Переименование функций, переменных и др.
- Панель диагностики (вывод проблем в коде в отдельную таблицу без запуска кода)

Answer (score 1):

Есть Kite, работает так же, как в PyCharm.

Для JupyterLab 3.0.x:

```
pip install "jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2"
```

Для JupyterLab 2.2.x:

```
pip install "jupyter-kite<2.0.0"
jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"
```

Правда, не смог в онлайн версию воткнуть его, что было бы замечательно при работе на телефоне, если ноута под рукой нет.

Comment: Сейчас пишет на их сайте, что движок недоступен для скачивания.